# Mac Maverrick AD binding

Tags: active-directory, mac

I have about 40 Macs on my AD Domain running OS X 10.9 (plus OD server). Recently the two MacPros (one aluminium case and one black shiny ash tray) have lost their binding to the AD, so I have unbound them from both servers. I have then bound the MacPro to the OD, with no problem, but when I try to bind to the AD through the OD Utility >AD service (entering the FQDN then the domain admin account and password or `DOMAIN\admin` and password) I immediately get the message `Authentication server could not be contacted`.

To resolve this I have checked:

- Server/client time is spot on
- Pinging the DC is fine
- DNS `nslookup` - forward and reverse to the DC is fine
- I can mount a DC share
- `Dig –t` ANY soa  returns both DCs
- Console – when console is cleared and I try to bind I get no log entries
- Wireshark – I can’t see any traffic between the client and server except one MDNS entry
- I can ssh to the machine

What further steps can I take to diagnose the cause of this issue?

Comment: The MDNS traffic suggests you may be using an AD domain name with a .local suffix. Is this the case?

Comment: No its not a .local

Comment: Solved!

We spent a lot of time trying to find this fault and trying to figure out if it was an OD AD or client Mac problem, we looked closely at our AD DNS as we had also noticed that our Global Catalog was slow to respond. see next

Comment: We then remembered that we had been asked us to turn off our DNS dynamic updates (last November) as our WAN provider said that our DNS was trying to update their DNS server, we did this, and there seemed to be no problem, PCs would bind OK, DNS worked fine. So having tried almost everything we could think off we turned on the DNS dynamic updates(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Servic es\ Tcpip\Parameters), and within half an hour our Global catalog worked and the Macs bound to the AD!